# Clicking on a link works perfectly but copy-pasting URL won't work

Tags: javascript, html

Today I encountered an interesting problem. When I navigate to a particular website and I click on a redirection URL, it works perfectly but copy-pasting the exact same URL will give me a 404 error!

It made me think that there was some JavaScript involved but after more investigation I found this URL: http://bib-alex.net/status.php?name=a-d-aadl-abw-zhrh--khald-a-ar_ptiff.pdf

Having looked at the source I cannot see any scripts. So I am a bit confused! Why does it behave like this and is it intentional?

Comment: I tried clicking & copy/paste in chrome and they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those links rely on the existence of [the `Referer` HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer).

If you click on one of those links, your browser will send a `Referer` header, set to the page you came from, in the request to the URL you're going to. If you copy/paste the URL, there is no originating page, so no such header is set.

Sites usually do this to prevent [leeching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking), e.g. because they don't want others to "steal" their bandwidth, or because they don't want others to download their files without also seeing their ads.